# Null pointer exception on intent.getStringExtra. : Android

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have a fragment and activity. From fragment I am passing a string named day to activity by putExtra . But getting null pointer exception when I am retrieving in an activity.

Passing a String.

```
private Intent i;

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            day = "Mon";
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEventActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("aKey", day);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
```

Retrieving a String :

```
 i = new Intent();
    dayOfWeek = i.getStringExtra("aKey");
    weekDay.setText(dayOfWeek);
```

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Show more code where is `i` in `AddEventActivity ` class

Comment: what is `i` variable and how you are creating it?

Comment: i is intent variable. Added in question

Comment: You will always get null. As you are creating new instance of Intent.

Comment: on which line you are getting exception

Answer (score 2):

```
String dayOfWeek = getIntent().getExtras().getString("aKey");
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getIntent()` in `onCreate` method of `AddEventActivity` Activity instead of `new Intent()` :

```
i = getIntent();
```

Also  add `null` check before accessing any method from `i`.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new `Intent` so there is no extra in it. you should retrieve passed intent in your `Activity`
try using

```
i = getIntent();
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

In activity , if you want receive data

```
i = getIntent();
dayOfWeek = i.getStringExtra("aKey");
weekDay.setText(dayOfWeek);
```